# tensorflow improper batch setup Check failed: cudnnSetTensorNdDescriptor when using upsampling

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I think I am setting up my batches wrong. If I run with the generated dataset it runs fine but with my own data I get an error.

If I take out the encoder (max pooling) and decoder (UpSampling2D) I don't get an error.

input size (304, 228, 1)

Generated: RUNS

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from natsort import natsorted
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

BATCH_SIZE = 4
EPOCHS = 20
LEARNING_RATE = 1e-4
RESET_TRAINING = True
INPUT_CHANNELS = 1
OUTPUT_CHANNELS = 1
LOSS_TYPE = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()

img_size = (304, 228)

# configure cuda
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)

class UnetModel(Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(UnetModel, *args, **kwargs)
        # -- Encoder -- #
        # Block encoder 1
        input_shape = (img_size[0], img_size[1], 1)

        # If you want to know more about why we are using `he_normal`:
        # https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319323/whats-the-difference-between-variance-scaling-initializer-and-xavier-initialize/319849#319849  
        # Or the excellent fastai course:
        # https://github.com/fastai/course-v3/blob/master/nbs/dl2/02b_initializing.ipynb
        initializer = 'he_normal'

        inputs = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)

        print("input shape ", input_shape)
        conv_enc_1 = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=initializer)(inputs)
        conv_enc_1 = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=initializer)(conv_enc_1)

        # Block encoder 2
        max_pool_enc_2 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv_enc_1)
        conv_enc_2 = layers.Conv2D(128, 5, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = initializer)(max_pool_enc_2)
        conv_enc_2 = layers.Conv2D(128, 5, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = initializer)(conv_enc_2)


        # Block decoder 1
        up_dec_4 = layers.Conv2D(64, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = initializer)(layers.UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv_enc_2))
        merge_dec_4 = layers.concatenate([conv_enc_1, up_dec_4], axis = 3)
        conv_dec_4 = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = initializer)(merge_dec_4)

        conv_dec_4 = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = initializer)(conv_dec_4)
        conv_dec_4 = layers.Conv2D(2, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = initializer)(conv_dec_4)
        # -- Dencoder -- #

        output = layers.Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'softmax')(conv_dec_4)

        self.model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = output)

    def call(self, x):
            return self.model(x)

model = UnetModel()

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(LEARNING_RATE), loss = LOSS_TYPE, metrics= [tf.keras.metrics.get('accuracy')])


dataset_debug = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.random.normal(shape = (BATCH_SIZE, img_size[0], img_size[1], 1)), tf.random.normal(shape = (BATCH_SIZE, img_size[0], img_size[1], 1)))).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

history = model.fit(dataset_debug, epochs=EPOCHS, shuffle=True)
```

Does NOT run
Here I am splitting the filenames into training and validation sets using **train_test_split** and reading in images in the parse_img_input function

```
# takes image filenames of uint8 and normalizes to 0-1 range
def parse_img_input(img_file, img_file_out):
    print("img file ", img_file)

    def _parse_input(img_file, img_file_out):
        # get img image
        d_filepath = img_file.numpy().decode()
        d_image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(
            tf.io.read_file(d_filepath), channels=1)
        d_image = tf.cast(d_image_decoded, tf.float32) / 255.0

        # get img image
        d_filepath_out = img_file_out.numpy().decode()
        d_image_decoded_out = tf.image.decode_jpeg(
            tf.io.read_file(d_filepath_out), channels=1)
        d_image_out = tf.cast(d_image_decoded_out, tf.float32) / 255.0

        # add channel dimension
        d_image = tf.expand_dims(d_image, -1)
        d_image_out = tf.expand_dims(d_image_out, -1)

        return d_image, d_image_out

    return tf.py_function(_parse_input,
                          inp=[img_file, img_file_out],
                          Tout=[tf.float32, tf.float32])


# depth_files_in, depth_files_out are lists of filenames

# split input data into train, test sets
X_train_file, X_test_file, y_train_file, y_test_file = train_test_split(depth_files_in, depth_files_out, 
                                                    test_size=0.2, 
                                                    random_state=0)

dataset_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train_file, y_train_file))
dataset_train = dataset_train.map(parse_img_input)

dataset_test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test_file, y_test_file))
dataset_test = dataset_test.map(parse_img_input)

history = model.fit(dataset_train, epochs=EPOCHS, shuffle=True, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, validation_data= dataset_test)
```

> F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:535] Check failed: cudnnSetTensorNdDescriptor(handle_.get(), elem_type, nd, dims.data(), strides.data()) == CUDNN_STATUS_SUCCESS (3 vs. 0)batch_descriptor: {count: 228 feature_map_count: 64 spatial: 152 0  value_min: 0.000000 value_max: 0.000000 layout: BatchDepthYX}

Comment: Can you post the exception output? :)

Comment: That's the output? Is there no Python Traceback?

Comment: No traceback on that no. Everything before is irrelevant

2021-06-07 13:43:31.879841: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2021-06-07 13:43:32.876504: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10

Comment: It has to do with maxpooling and then upsampling but not sure how.

Comment: @TheClockTwister if I change the maxpooling to using a convolution with a stride of 2 I get a different maybe more telling error

Conv2DSlowBackpropInput: Size of out_backprop doesn't match computed: actual = 1, computed = 114 spatial_dim: 3 input: 228 filter: 3 output: 1 stride: 2 dilation: 1